# Highcharts Sankey diagram issue

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I am implementing a Sankey Diagram using Highcharts JS V4.0.
Included Sankey.js just below Highcharts.js in my header file.
When I integrate Sankey diagram , gives me error as ' `Uncaught Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17` ' in console.

I did research on this error, and found solution to include Highcharts-more.js.
Tried the same, but which results me to having another error ' `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded highchart` '.

I am wondering, if HighchartV4.0 supports Sankey Diagram?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: No, highcharts 4 does not support Sankey diagrams, as you can see by the changelog when it was added: https://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog#highcharts-v6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors are caused by not supporting this type of series in version 4.0.
Sankey series type was added to Highcharts since version 6.0.0 (2017-10-04).

Changelog: https://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog

Answer (score 1):

Sankey Diagram not supported for Highchart v4.0.
But, added two Highchart versions in header like this-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highchart_v6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sankey.js"></script>
<script>
   var HighchartsNew = Highcharts;
   Highcharts = null;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highcharts_v4.js"></script>
```

Solved my problem. 
May be it will will help someone.